# HTTParty : undefined method `code' error

Tags: ruby, httparty

Getting error: ./http.rb:13: undefined method `code' for # (NoMethodError)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class Foo
  include HTTParty
end

# Simple get with full url
r = Foo.get('http://www.google.com/')

p r.code
```

Comment: What version of Ruby / HTTParty are you using? With Ruby 1.9.3p392 and HTTParty 0.11 your code works fine for me (prints 200 as expected).

Comment: Could you give the full error trace.

Comment: ruby 1.8.5
httparty-0.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Include HTTParty adds the method code of the specified module to the Foo class as well. See [mixin](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)!

```
module HTTParty
  module AllowedFormatsDeprecation
    def get
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

mixin HTTParty into Foo should work

Comment: Cannot leave comments, so my answer was mainly to RubyLovely answer.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you see there documentation? `Response` class is inside the `HTTParty` module. Thus it has to be called like `HTTParty:Response`.

Comment: you can put it as your comments, you are putting you opinion or confusion as an answer in `answer` area. it's not fare.

Comment: The code of the topic starter should work correctly, as he includes `Httparty` module into `Foo`. This way we can use `get` method. The response is then assigned to r on which `code` method is called.

Comment: `Foo.get` is possible as `get` is a class method of `HTTParty` module.

Comment: Look at the topic starter code. He doesn't call `code` inside `Foo` class.

Comment: `Response` is a class not a module.

Comment: `r = Foo.get('http://www.google.com/')` result of the `get` is assigned to r. r is `HTTParty::Response` and we can use `code` on it.

Comment: Did you try it? BTW I have deleted the post. I have no time to check here. I will at my home.